# How to create histogram table? R

Tags: r, histogram

I am trying to create a histogram using frequency data. Here is the data:

```
  x         freq
1 Buick      80
2 Cadillac   80
3 Chevrolet  320 
4 Pontiac    150
5 SAAB       114
6 Saturn     60
```

When I try:

```
hist(carMake)
```

I get:

[image]

Then I tried:

```
df = as.data.frame(cbind(Overall.Cond = 1:6, Freq = c(80,80,320,150,114,60)))
df
df.freq = as.vector(rep(df$Overall.Cond, df$Freq))
hist(df.freq)
```

And I get:

[image]

Which is fine, but I would like there to be no spaces in between the bars, & labels instead of the numbers 1 through 6.

How can I do this?

Comment: You don't want a `histogram()`, you want a `barplot()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - barplot | How to control space and width of bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149590/r-barplot-how-to-control-space-and-width-of-bars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `barplot`, since you already got your frequencies?

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="
x         freq
1 Buick      80
2 Cadillac   80
3 Chevrolet  320 
4 Pontiac    150
5 SAAB       114
6 Saturn     60")
df
barplot(df$freq, names.arg = df$x)
```